# BigInteger > 32 bit left shift issue

Tags: java, bit-shift

I'm looking at `BigInteger` as a big number (practically) and I'm trying to perform a left shift on the number. So, when I perform a 32 bit left shift on the number (I'm currently using 2), I get the same number again (which is expected for an integer).

Is there any way I can increase the number of bits used to store the number? I know I can use `long`; however, I want to cross the 64 bit limit. Is there any way I could do that?

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Note that the behaviour you're talking about makes sense for `int`, but not `BigInteger`...

Comment: do you mean shift or rotation? because a shift of anything not zero (and -1 in some cases) will not result in the same number.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios not using the "binary string" definition no, but in java the shift amount (for `int` and `long`) is taken modulo the number of bits in the type, so `x << 0 == x << 32` (for `x` an `int`)

Comment: Try `myBigInt = myBigInt.shiftLeft(32);`

Comment: @harold thanks for clearing that up :) in that case BigInteger.shiftX is not the same as an arithmetic shift, right?

Comment: Probably you made a tiny mistake, like not assigning the shifted big int to itself.

Comment: Yes, I did make  a mistake. I did not assign it to itself. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to say exactly what your problem is without seeing any actual code, but note that `BigInteger` instances are immutable. If you write `aBigInt.shiftLeft(32)` the instance referenced by `aBigInt` is not changed. Instead, a new `BigInteger` instance with the result of the operation is returned. Try: `aBigInt = aBigInt.shiftLeft(32)`.